# seperate #define on same project in different solutions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a c++ project which is included in two different solutions. I want the project to have different `#define` constants under each solution. Is there a way to do it?

My best solution is to build different project file with same c++ codes in it, but its a fuss, and I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Do *all* of your project files need the macro? Or just some? Perhaps split it up into *three* projects? One for the independent files, and two for the files that needs different setups?

Comment: Also, having multiple projects that share source files are no big deal really. You don't need to copy the files, just add the exact same source and header files to both projects.

Comment: You can probably give your compiler a flag that defines a macro. In gcc it is `-D`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: There are macros like #ifdef, #if, #defined, #else, and #elif.
With these you can control the flow and maybe use a different #define directive based on such conditions...

Comment: By the way, if you use Visual Studio, you really already have two different projects for each "project" in the solution: Release and Debug. Why not add a new configurations like `Debug - Variant1` and `Debug - Variant2` (with names more relevant to your situation of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to conditionally pull solution-specific property sheets from the corresponding solution folder.

```xml
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import
        Project="$(SolutionDir)SolutionSpecific.props"
        Condition="exists('$(SolutionDir)SolutionSpecific.props')"
        Label="solution-specific props" />
</ImportGroup>
```

where `SolutionSpecific.props` is a property sheet file containing macro definition.

Comment: i like this approach, this is best for me, but it involves lots of projects to be changed. what i did instead is add to the current property sheet all projects are using a preprocessor defind with $(SolutionName) and then do all the #ifdef in the files accordingly. but i think your solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef Proj
    #define Bla "Klaf"
#else
    #define Bla "Flak"
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << Bla << '\n';
}
```

And then control the `#ifdef` with a command line argument on your compiler.

Here the one that is compiling with `-D Proj` (this flag is for gcc, MSVC uses `/D` I think) prints `Flak`, and the other prints `Klaf`:

https://godbolt.org/z/TEKvrYdxG

Comment: im runing the build from visual studio and not as a command line.

Comment: @JoeArnon: VS defines a variable for each project already if it's an DLL, something along the lines of <PROJECTNAME>_EXPORT. Check in the project properties under C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions. Add your own as needed.

Comment: yes, Ive added $(SolutionName) in the property sheet all projects are using.